# Java and Jconn4 support for Sybase 16.3

Tags: java, sybase, jconnect

I have got a project wherein my database going to upgrade to /sybase 16.3 version. My current applications has the either jconn2 and Jconn4 dependencies to connect to current Sybase version.
Can anyone help me to cover following points:

1. Is jconn2/jconn4 supports Sybase 16.3?
2. is there any link wherein i can find this support information

Comment: 1. Don't know. 2. Not here.

Comment: You should also specify which Sybase (or rather SAP now) product you mean i.e. ASE, Anywhere, IQ etc.

Comment: By Sybase i mean ASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can review the various versions of JConnect here:
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBCON/jConnect+Driver+Overview

Watch out for this change as well:

**Major changes:**
from jconn3.jar to jconn4.jar from SDK 15.5 ESD#3 and higher DYNAMIC_PREPARE changed the default setting from false in jconn3 to true with jconn4.
ref: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20155.1550/html/newfesd/CIHCIIJE.htm

This changed caused us serious issues with spinlock contention in procedure cache after a SDK patch where this was enabled.